# Is there a way of forcing a Network Fix location?

Tags: android

I'm making my first app here, I use both GPS and Network (for when GPS is not available) to update location. 
I'm now testing how the network location works alone, but i find that sometimes it takes a bit of time to retrieve the real location, even with the < 1500m accuracy. 
(I take google maps as example) I notice that i'm off the accuracy circle and takes a while to update, and when i say "a while" could be more than 30 secs or a minute.

So my question is, is there a way of forcing a Location update using the Network provider?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyLocationOverlay i think you have no any control on location update intervals.

You can try to implement your own overlay item with own undelying location update code where you can specify your own values for location update frequency. See `Overlay` and `LocationManager` docs for details.